# Is there a way for making the re-write rule exclude some folders?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want this rule to NOT run if the url has /Users or /Forums in the url.

How can I do this?

**Update**
What about file extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition that excludes such URL paths:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Users|Forums)(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: so I remove the 'rewritebase /' or keep that?

Comment: what if I want it to ignore a specific file extension, like .cfm

Comment: @Blankman: Just add another condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.cfm$`